# How to get list of months from today to january?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i tried to generate list of months from today to january, with this code

```
select now() - (interval '1' month * generate_series(0,7))
```

i need to set up the column number so how can i get all the list of  month without set up the column number if today is november?

Comment: I don't understand, can you also paste the expected output? It would be easier for people who try to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select *
from generate_series(date_trunc('year', now()), date_trunc('month', now()),
                     interval '1 month') g(mon);
```

If you want all the days from todays date going backward:

```
select *
from generate_series(now(), date_trunc('year', now()),
                     interval '-1 month') g(mon);
```

However, you have to think about what you would want to do if today were, say, Aug 31 and the month is February.

Comment: how do i get the today's date, i try adding date_trunc day at the end but it gives me error

Answer (score 1):

```
with
    __start as(
        select
            date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)::date as start_month -- Starts from this month
            --(date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) + '1 month'::interval)::date as start_month -- Starts from next month
    ),
    __end as(
        select
            start_month,
            (start_month + ((13 - extract(month from start_month))::text || ' months')::interval)::date as end_month -- Includes January in results
            -- (start_month + ((12 - extract(month from start_month))::text || ' months')::interval)::date as end_month -- Does not include January
        from
            __start
    )
select
    generate_series(start_month, end_month, '1 month'::interval)::date as intervening_month
from
    __end
```

Will output the current month, every month between now and January and January itself typecast to `date`

I've included alternatives which are commented out for excluding the current month, and excluding January